# Make Checkbox Checked From array value Laravel Js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-9

I'm using [Jquery Multiselect](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-List-with-Checkboxes-MultiSelect/jquery.multiselect.js) with checkboxes

My Select tag

```
<div class="form-group mb-30">
<label class="font-sm color-text-mutted mb-10">Educational
    Qualification *</label>
<select class="form-control" name="educational_qualification[]" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Graduation Not Required">
        <option value="Graduation Not Required">Graduation Not Required
        </option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Graduate">
        <option value="Any Graduate">Any Graduate</option>
        <option value="B.A">B.A</option>
        ...
        <option value="B.U.M.S">B.U.M.S</option>
        <option value="Other Graduate">Other Graduate</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Postgraduate">
        <option value="Any Postgraduate">Any Postgraduate</option>
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        ...
        <option value="Post Graduation Not Required">Post Graduation Not
            Required</option>
        <option value="Other Post Graduate">Other Post Graduate</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Doctoral/Ph.D">
        <option value="Any Doctorate">Any Doctorate</option>
        ...
        <option value="Doctorate Not Required">Doctorate Not Required
        </option>
        <option value="Other Doctorate">Other Doctorate</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have this value as array `$job->education`

[image]

**I want to make the checkboxes checked if the value matches**

Comment: Hi, your select-tag is pure html or you are using php to generate options inside it and from where do you get the $job->education values ?

Comment: @Swati it's pure html

Comment: I am not seeing direct way to do this because you are generating options via html and plugin has an option with json data were you can passed the `checked` attribute which will work . See [this](https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect/tree/d9f4c2801e6c147769fd5421ec7be7192315e7e5) documentation has example in it . Also, there is one way other then that i.e : You can trigger there checkbox event which will do work for you [setting selected options ..etc]